# Approximation to $\mathbb{E}(X/Y)$

Tags: probability, approximation

Let $X,Y$ are two random variables which are not necessarily independent. It is easy to get $\mathbb{E}(X)$ ann $\mathbb{E}(Y)$. I want to know: is there some approximation to $\mathbb{E}(\frac{X}{Y})$?

**[Update]**
The background is that I want to calculate the expectation of Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient - $\mathbb{E}(\rho_{xy})$.

The Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient is $\rho_{xy} = \frac{Cov_{xy}}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}$

It is easily to get $\mathbb{E}(Cov_{xy})$ and $\mathbb{E}(\sigma_x\sigma_y)$, so I want to know a approximation to get $\mathbb{E}(\rho_{xy})$ from the above two value.

Comment: The expected value of a constant is the constant itself. For random variables $X$ and $Y$, $Cov_{xy}$ by which I assume you mean $E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]$ is a _constant._  So, when you write $E[Cov_{xy}]$, its value is just $Cov_{xy}$, unless there is some _other_ random variable with respect to which you are computing the correlation.  That is, are there _three_ random variables $X,Y,Z$ and $Cov_{xy}$ is the _conditional_ covariance of $X$ and $Y$ conditioned on $\{Z = \alpha\}$, say, and you are now trying to find the unconditional covariance?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Please see the second answer of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10981/computing-mathematical-expectation-of-the-correlation-coefficient-or-r2-in-li

Comment: I _have_ looked at the question and answer on stats.SE.  There the issue was _estimating_ the variance, covariance, correlation coefficient, etc. given $n$ i.i.d. samples from $(X,Y)$ with unknown joint distribution, and you got answers for that.  **Here** you are **not** talking about $n$ i.i.d. samples, or estimating $Cov_{xy}$ from such samples, etc. but just about two random variables $X$ and $Y$.  I ask again, _what_ is the meaning of $E[Cov_{xy}]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $f(x,y)$, $E[X/Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{y} \ f(x,y)\ dx\ dy$ (assuming that converges absolutely).  Similarly, if they have a joint probability mass function $p(x,y)$, 
$E[X/Y] = \sum_x \sum_y \frac{x}{y} p(x,y)$.

Let $\mu = E[Y]$.
If you can treat $Y - \mu$ as small compared to $\mu$ (in particular if there is $c>0$ such that
$c < Y < 2 \mu - c$ almost surely) then 
$$E[X/Y] = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \frac{E[X (Y - \mu)^j]}{ \mu^{j+1}}$$
so you could use a partial sum of that as an approximation.